# Design QA checklist

Tags: quality-assurance, checklist

I'm coming up with a checklist for QA to check on designs after a feature has been built on a product before it can be released.

Design QA checklist

[ ] matches with design specs (colors, spacing, text styles, etc)
[ ] interactions and behaviours 
[ ] edge cases
[ ] local variations (with local language, currency)

For desktop features
[ ] on smaller screens / tablet 
[ ] on large screen

For mobile
[ ] on small phone
[ ] on larger phone

What do you think? am I missing out of anything that should be checked

Comment: You are missing Section 508 - Compatibility for users with disabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pure opinion, but...

In my experience UX and UI needs to be checked by the UX and UI team. QA can ensure everything works, but in terms of layout and UI, that's really something that should belong to the UX/UI team.

Design specs can rarely account for everything and often contradict in various contexts. It's not easy for a QA team that didn't actually design the UI to be able to judge whether or not "it's up to spec".

Comment: Exactly...it's pure opinion based

Comment: I have the same experience. You can set QA a task to check the design, but going through checking font sizes, colours, borders, backgrounds etc is a laborious task and it comes much easier to people who have a design background.

Comment: the UX and UI team will be biased towards the most typical user stories, particularly the ones that were seen in user testing sessions and those which impacted design decisions. The design QA needs to check ALL possibilities to ensure the feature provides a good experience for each and every scenario.

Answer (score 2):

*According to Nielsen Norman*

**Quality assurance impacts the user experience: when things don’t work, users question their understanding and develop superstitions and inefficient workarounds.**

Quality assurance (QA) and user experience (UX) have a two-way relationship:
Most obvious, usability is a quality measure for design. To ensure usability, a good UX thus requires QA thinking.

Beyond the user interface itself, many other quality issues also impact the total UX.

**Usability as QA**

First Law of Usability: Your design will be tested by users — your only choice is whether to run the test yourself before launch so that you can fix the inevitable problems while it’s cheap instead of playing expensive catch-up later.)

[Read more](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/quality-assurance-ux/)

**Quality Assurance on the web**, often referred to as QA, is a proof and review of a product or deliverable - in our case web applications and websites. QA is independent of the design and development processes in order to test a product’s many uses in the myriad of ways an enduser, especially those unfamiliar with the software, might. The QA process is expected to discover design issues and development errors while testing a product’s user interface (UI) and gauging the user experience (UX).

[Read more](https://www.unleashed-technologies.com/blog/2015/04/30/what-quality-assurance-web)